# Webpack Generating Random Character in Browser

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to add webpack 3.3.5 to my existing AngularJS project.  I am following the instructions on the webpack website at https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#using-a-configuration.  The command line for building my bundle.js is working just fine and the file looks good.  However, when I try to open the index.html file in the browser (Chrome and IE) I get an error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

When I go to view the error location there appears to be random characters in the JavaScript file below the two harmony import lines.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash__ = __webpack_require__(1);
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash__);
ï»¿

function component() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash___default.a.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
    return element;
}
```

When I open the actual bundle.js file in Visual Studio I do not see these characters.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash__ = __webpack_require__(1);
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash__);
﻿

function component() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lodash___default.a.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
    return element;
}
```

Can anyone help? Here are my files.

**src/index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function component() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**src/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

**dist/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include this in your index.html for UTF-8

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Read more about this here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this begs another question...why is this even being added by webpack?  What purpose does it server to require the user to specify the character set?

Comment: Wow! This took me a while to fix this, thank you very much. And it's so simple!

Other search terms (error for me): "SyntaxError: Unexpected character '┬┐'
lodash webpack electron